# why the lock field of Linux kernel's rwlock_t is unsigned int

Tags: linux, rwlock

In Linux 2.6.11.12, the `rwlock_t` is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned int lock;
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK
    unsigned magic;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT
    unsigned int break_lock;
#endif
} rwlock_t;
```

In the definition of `rwlock_t`, the `lock` field is `unsigned int`. When we want to get a read lock, `read_lock()` will eventually call the `_raw_read_trylock()`

```
static inline int _raw_read_trylock(rwlock_t *lock)
{
    atomic_t *count = (atomic_t *)lock;
    atomic_dec(count);
    if (atomic_read(count) >= 0)
        return 1;
    atomic_inc(count);
    return 0;
}
```

In this function, we call `atomic_dec()` to decrease the `lock` and check whether it is greater than or equal to zero. But **since the `lock` is an `unsigned int`, `lock` will always greater than 0!** That is, this function will always return 1.

I guessed that the `atomic_read()` convert the result to a `int`, but in i386 arch, it is defined as

```
#define atomic_read(v)      ((v)->counter)
```

and I have no idea how `unsigned int lock` works.

Comment: It is being cast to `atomic_t` so interpreted as one (which in turn is [defined as `int`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L175)).  I'm no kernel guru but perhaps you are on to something here, though.

Comment: ouch, I did neglect it. thanks :)